# How to properly implement a drag and drop list with checkboxes?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to make a checklist of items that I can search with an input element and re-order with drag/drop. The issue I am running into is that when I toggle "Show only checked" on, then re-order with drag/drop, then toggle "Show only checked" again, the full list does not re-render.

How can I fix this so that I am able to re-order when using the searchable input element, and is there a better way to manage my checklist of items rather than maintaining two separate states?

Here's my [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/drag-and-drop-list-7vwh55)

Comment: you removed those elements with `setList(listCopy);`, listCopy is a clone of filteredList, so you need to find a way to add those elements back before updating list. Heres a possible upgrade, filteredList doesnt need to be a state, you can use a normal variable for it, this way filteredList will always derive from list so you dont have to manage 2 states

Comment: I'm struggling to see how I can accomplish the task without managing two states because I need to track if items getting checked or unchecked when there is text in the search box.

Comment: theres not enough space in comment, ill show you what i meant in answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently in your code you are using 2 states list and filteredList and switching between them

```
const [list, setList] = useState(defaultList);
const [filteredList, setFilteredList] = useState(defaultList);
const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);
```

Instead you can use a variable to store filteredList, this way filteredList is guarenteed to reflect from list, so when you change the order you only need to change them in list.

```
const [list, setList] = useState(defaultList);
const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);
const filteredList = checked ? list.filter((item) => item.checked === true) : list;
```

I have not tested this code but the idea should work.